# Extract time part from TimeStamp column in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently I'm using `MyTimeStampField-TRUNC(MyTimeStampField)` to extract the time part from a timestamp column in Oracle.

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL
```

This returns

> +00 13:12:07.100729

This works OK for me, to extract the time part from a timestamp field, but I'm wondering if there is a better way (may be using a built-in function of ORACLE) to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about [EXTRACT()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) function?

Comment: if use the extract function, should be wrote something like `SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) || ':' ||EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)|| ':' ||EXTRACT(SECOND FROM  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL;` this is more efficient wich the method i actually use?

Comment: @RRUZ perhaps also add leading zeroes if timepart has only 1 digit: SELECT LPAD(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 2, '0') || ':' || LPAD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 2, '0') || ':' || LPAD(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 2, '0') FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 6):

You could always do something like:

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'hh24:mi:ss'),'hh24:mi:ss') from dual
```

I believe this will work with timestamps as well.

Answer (score 3):

You want just date then use

```
to_char(cast(SYSDATE as date),'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

and if you want just time then use

```
to_char(cast(SYSDATE as date),'hh24:mi:ss')
```

the parameters are making all the changed

```
'DD-MM-YYYY'
```

and

```
'hh24:mi:ss'
```

Comment: so the final statement would be be for the above statement            SELECT to_char(cast(SYSDATE as date),'DD-MM-YYYY'),  to_char(cast(SYSDATE as date),'hh24:mi:ss') FROM DUAL

Answer (score 2):

```sql
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'hh24:mi:ss'),'hh24:mi:ss') from dual
```

This gives the timestamp for 1hour less than the actual.

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

```
Select EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (SYSDATE - trunc(sysdate)) DAY TO SECOND ) From dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not so elegant, but it works for me.

```
SELECT TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) - TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM dual
-----------------
0,851863425925926
```

And without last subtraction you convert TIMESTAMP to DATE with time, i.e.

```
SELECT TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) FROM dual
-----------------
20.04.2023 20:31:02
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select hour(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe you can make your answer better by specifying how it is better then the question's solution, as well as following the help section to properly format your code.