# SQL Timestamp to INT,newest record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem with converting timestamp column, example of value:

```
val  name   timestamp
1    adam   01-NOV-12
2    adam   02-DEC-13
3    adam   01-DEC-12
```

I need result:

```
val  name   timestamp
2    adam   02-DEC-13
```

I want to select newest record for DISTINCT value in column

I have tried `SELECT CAST(timestamp AS DATE) as TIME` but not working

I have also tried `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` but it's working for me only when format is like this one:

`'001-01-01 00:00:00'`

Can anyone help me to convert this value(`10-AUG-12`) to INT?

Or maybe without conversion i can select from this table only newest record using actual timestamp?

EDIT:

I have tried `ORDER_BY timestamp DESC`

but it gives me on output :

```
val  name   timestamp
2    adam   02-DEC-13
1    adam   01-DEC-12
3    adam   01-NOV-12
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951858/extract-time-part-from-timestamp-column-in-oracle

Comment: selecting newest record should be easy using order by, it would be better if you post sample data and more detailed logic of what you are trying

Comment: `select * from the_table order by timestamp desc fetch first 1 rows only`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

```
SELECT val,name,timestamp
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY timestamp desc) rn
    FROM T t1
) t1
where rn = 1
```

Comment: this answer is  working when in 4th row we change `FROM T t1` to `FROM t1`
Thank You

Comment: hello, could You tell me some more, how to use this to multiple tables? i am trying to add two more tables using inner join but it's now working;/ could You give me a hint? thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may use `FIRST` aggregate function ( `KEEP...DENSE_RANK` )

```
select MAX(VAL) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY TIME_STAMP DESC ) as Val,
       Name,
       MAX(TIME_STAMP) FROM t
       GROUP BY Name;
```

Or correlated sub-query

```
SELECT *
  FROM t o
WHERE time_stamp = (
        SELECT MAX(time_stamp)
        FROM t i
        WHERE i.name = o.name
        );
```

Or `row_number()` technique as shown in other answer.

Comment: Why would you use `in` instead of `=`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Sure..I'll make it `=`.  It's a habit to use `IN` by default for sub-queries ;-)

Comment: . . I think that is a bad habit.  It could affect optimization.

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak hey, what `t o` and `t i` means? in `FROM t o ` and `FROM t oi`  also in `WHERE i.name = o.name`   thanks

Comment: @sygneto : `o` and `i` are table aliases used to distinguish references to table outside and inside sub-query. `t` is any table name. You should use it as `yourtablename i` and `yourtablename o` . Google correlated sub-query to know more